# Is 'teach a school' in this context correct?

Tags: verbs, collocations, formal-language

I am reading [A woman makes a plan: advice for a lifetime of adventure, beauty, and success](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1984878506) by Maye Musk, but I've never seen the use of 'teach' in 'teaching this modeling school' in this context:

> “Here was this beautiful woman,” she will say, “who is teaching this modeling school. Great model, dresses terribly. Just terribly.”

I learned from [here](https://www.usingenglish.com/forum/threads/teach-in-at-a-school.157708/) that the correct one should be 'teach at a school'. Is the collocation 'teaching a school' idiomatic? If not, why is 'teach a class' correct?

Comment: A single teacher doesn't teach a whole school, unless it's a very small one. I find "Here **was** this woman... who **is** teaching" strange as well.

Comment: @KateBunting But that's exactly what I read, and as so far as I have cruised through the book the diction in the book is very good except for this minor issue.

Comment: I don't know anything about modelling schools; maybe in this one  the number of students was small enough for one woman to teach them all.  I meant that in an ordinary school (for children), that's why we say _teach a class_ but not usually _teach a school_.

Answer (score -1):

"Teach" is a transitive or intransitive verb (meaning to instruct). Your quoted text is acceptable.